# Sharepoint event receiver not working

Tags: sharepoint

I have an Event Handler that overrides the ItemAdded method. This works fine on my DEV environment but on my LIVE environment it doesn't fire. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the way I have set it up.

The class is declared like this.

```
public class SitesEventHandler : SPItemEventReceiver {

    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties) {
        //... code removed.
    }
}
```

I've added the event handler like this:

```
SPList sites = web.Lists["Sites"];
sites.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded, "MossServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6e99", "MossServices.SitesEventHandler");
```

I know that the event has been added but I'm wondering if there is a step I've missed out.

**EDIT**
I have found that it runs fine when I use it as an administrator but not as anyone else. I must admit I suspected it could be permissions. Would anyone be able to tell me why it works for a systems administrator but not a content manager? Again, is there anything in the set up I should have done? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here wasn't with the way the event handler/receiver was registered or with the code within the class. It was a problem with permissions.

What really helped me was looking in the logs that Sharepoint writes:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\LOGS

This link helped me with my particular problem:
http://sharenotes.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/cannot-open-log-for-source-you-may-not-have-write-access/

Hope this helps someone. This does have the feel of a dirty hack, but sometimes the option to entirely scrap a system and re-do the years of previous dirty hacks just isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

The PublicKeyToken in your assembly name does not look correct. It looks too short

Comment: I edited my public key token to make it look a lot smaller. I was being overly paranoid about security.

Comment: I should state that I edited the public key when I was posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using feature to register the event handler?
Did you activate that feature?

Or maybe you can just use  [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) to register your event receiver

Comment: I used a console app to register the event handler using the code you see in the second snippit in my question.